# Android MediaPlayer: How to stop if another audio file is being loaded?

Tags: java, android, audio

I have a problem with the Android MediaPlayer. As soon as a new sound file is clicked by user input, the old one does not stop, so all audio files overlap.

I already tried common methods like MediaPlayer.stop(); and
MediaPlayer.release();

These methods always result in an app crash, although they are called in the correct order

```
public void Abspielen(String Datei) {
    try {
        AndreasPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, getResources().getIdentifier(Datei, "raw", getPackageName()));
        AndreasPlayer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Abspielen("filename");
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out the following solution:

```
    public void Abspielen(String Datei) {

    try {

        stopKnopf = findViewById(R.id.fab2);
        stopKnopf.show();

        try  {
            if (AndreasPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                AndreasPlayer.reset();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }

        AndreasPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, getResources().getIdentifier(Datei, "raw", getPackageName()));

        AndreasPlayer.start();

        stopKnopf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AndreasPlayer.reset();
                stopKnopf.hide();
            }
        });

        AndreasPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                AndreasPlayer.reset();
                stopKnopf.hide();
            }

        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```